# Sending order data to the database with Prisma/schema ORM prisma

Tags: next.js, prisma

It's a project made in NextJS and Prisma that involves a schema with related data in create and connect.
I'm trying to create an order with Prisma in the database and I'm getting: `API resolved without sending a response for /api/order, this may result in stalled requests.`
I thought it would be correct, but it's like the problem is some mismatch of information.
OBS.: In the database I already have 1 tenant, 1 customer, 1 shippingaddress and 1 product created for the test.

I will leave the codes below separately.

"Code that sends the data to the API"

```
if(order.shippingAddress) {
console.log('Enviando requisição para "/api/order"');
let response = await fetch("/api/order",
{
method: 'POST',
body: JSON.stringify({
status: 'preparing',
orderDate: '2022-12-04',
userId: 1,
shippingAddress: {
id: 1,
street: 'Rua de Cá',
number: `200`,
cep: '32324432',
city: 'Caruaru',
neighborhood: 'Salgado',
state: 'SP'
},
shippingPrice: 9.14,
paymentType: 'card',
paymentChange: 0,
cupom: 'AEIOU',
cupomDiscount: 14.3,
products: [
{ product: { id: 1,
image: '/tmp/burguer.png',
categoryName: 'Tradicional',
name: 'Texas Burguer',
price: 25.50,
description: '1 ingrediente do produto, 2 ingrediente do produto, 3 ingrediente do produto, 4 ingrediente do produto' }, qt: 1 }
],
subtotal: 204,
total: 198.84
}),
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
});
let json = await response.json();
console.log('Resposta de /api/order:', json);
if(json.status) {
router.push(`/${data.tenant.slug}/orderId`);
alert('Pedido enviado!');
}
} else {
alert("Problemas no servidor, por favor entre em contato com o restaurante!")
}
```

---

"API that sends the data for creation (/api/order)"

```
import { NextApiHandler } from "next";
import orderApi from "../../../libs/orderApi";

const handlerPost: NextApiHandler = async(req, res) => {
const {
status,
orderDate,
userId,
shippingPrice,
shippingAddress,
paymentType,
paymentChange,
cupom,
cupomDiscount,
products,
subtotal,
total
} = req.body;

const newOrder = await orderApi.addOrder(
status, 
orderDate, 
userId, 
shippingPrice, 
shippingAddress,
paymentType, 
paymentChange, 
cupom, 
cupomDiscount, 
products, 
subtotal, 
total
).catch(() => {
res.status(500).json({ error: 'Falha no servidor, entre em contato com o restaurante!' });
});
    
if(newOrder) {
res.status(201).json({ status: true, order: newOrder })
}

}

const handler: NextApiHandler = (req, res) => {
switch(req.method) {
case 'GET':
handler(req, res);
break;
case 'POST':
handlerPost(req, res);
break;  
}
}

export default handler;
```

---

"Types created separately from Address, CartItem and Product1"

```
export type Address = {
id: number;
cep: string;
street: string;
number: string;
neighborhood: string;
city: string;
state: string;
complement?: string | undefined;
}

export type Product1 = {
id: number;
image: string;
categoryName: string;
name: string;
price: number;
description?: string;
}

import { Product1 } from "./Product";

export type CartItem = {
qt: number;
product: Product1;
}
```

---

"API to order the prisma.create"

```
import { Address } from "../types/Address";
import { CartItem } from "../types/CartItem";
import prisma from "./prisma";

export default {
addOrder: async (
status: string,
orderDate: string,
userId: number,
shippingAddress: Address,
shippingPrice: number,
paymentType: string,
paymentChange: number,
cupom: string,  
cupomDiscount: number,
products: CartItem[],
subtotal: number,
total: number
) => {
return await prisma.order.create({
data: {
status: status,
orderDate: orderDate,
shippingPrice: shippingPrice,
client: {
connect: { id: userId }
},
shippingAddress: {
...shippingAddress
},
paymentType: paymentType,
paymentChange: paymentChange,
cupom: cupom,
cupomDiscount: cupomDiscount,
products: {
create: products.map((cartItem) => ({
qt: cartItem.qt,
product: {
connect: { id: cartItem.product.id }
}
}))
},
subtotal: subtotal,
total: total
}
});
}
}
```

---

"Connection to the Database"

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/delivery?schema=public"
```

---

"Schema Prisma"

```
generator client {
provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
provider = "postgresql"
url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Tenant {
id           Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
name         String            @unique
document     String
color1       String
color2       String
image        String
cep          String
city         String
neighborhood String
number       String
state        String
street       String
timeOpen     String
timeClose    String
products     Product[]
clients      Client[]

@@map("tenants")
}

model Client {
id       Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
name     String
document String
tenantId Int
address  ShippingAddress[]
orders   Order[]

tenant Tenant @relation(fields: [tenantId], references: [id])

@@map("clients")
}

model Order {
id            Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
cupom         String
cupomDiscount Float
orderDate     String
paymentType   String
paymentChange Float
shippingPrice Float
status        String
subtotal      Float
total         Float
userId      Int
products      ProductOrder[]

client Client @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

@@map("orders")
}

model ShippingAddress {
id           Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
street       String
number       String
cep          String
city         String
neighborhood String
state        String
userId     Int

client Client @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

@@map("shippingaddresses")
}

model Product {
id            Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
categoryName  String
description   String
image         String
name          String
price         Float
tenantId      Int
productOrders ProductOrder[]

tenant Tenant @relation(fields: [tenantId], references: [id])

@@map("products")
}

model ProductOrder {
id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
qt        Int
productId Int
orderId   Int

product Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
order   Order   @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id])

@@map("productorders")
}
```

I tried to create a request with the data sent to the database through ORM Prisma, I expected the codes to be correct but I get an error as if some information is not compatible with what the API expects to execute the "prisma.order.create".